# overridding vendor file in lumen not working

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I want to override vendor class `EloquentUserProvider`.
I have created one same file in `app/Ovverides` folder

this is my composer.json

```
"exclude-from-classmap": [
            "vendor\\Illuminate\\Auth\\EloquentUserProvider.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "App\\Ovverides\\": "app/Ovverides/"
        }
```

after running  `composer dump-autoload`  , the file is not overridden

Comment: Does the second one not have a namespace?

Comment: you would just configure auth to use a different user provider if you were trying to not use the default one ... any particular reason you are trying to change the provider?

Comment: currently it has namespace Illuminate\Auth;

Comment: what will be the best way to override a vendor class , can you please mention steps

Comment: Does it exist in your service providers config?

Comment: in bootstrap/app.php i have this 
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::class,
    App\Ovverides\EloquentUserProvider::class
);